# Let $b_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_{ni},$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_{ni}=0$, do we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0?$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Let 
$$b_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_{ni}.$$
If for each $i=1,\cdots,n$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_{ni}=0.$$
Can we claim that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0?$$

Comment: Do you know Cesaro-Stolz lemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for each $i=1,\cdots,n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_{ni}=0$, then
for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $i=1,\cdots,n$, there exists $N_i$ s.t. for $n>N_i$, we have
$$|\xi_{ni}|<\varepsilon.$$
Let $N=\max_{1\le i\le n}{N_i}$, then for $n>N$ and all $i=1,\cdots,n$, we have
$$|\xi_{ni}|<\varepsilon.$$
Furthermore, we have
$$|b_n|\le\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n|\xi_{ni}|<\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon=\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

No (with $\xi_{ni}=i^2/n$, say, you have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$).

Comment: "If for each $i=1,\cdots,n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_{ni}=0.$"

Comment: @RRL: And?.. ($\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(i^2/n)=0$.)

Comment: (And I don't understand what $i=n$ would mean here. I just read it as "$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_{ni}=0$ for each *fixed* $i$", most naturally matching the title.)

Comment: I'm just saying either the question or the answer needs to be clarified. On the other hand, this is a good answer with that clarification (+1).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I post a proof above. Welcome for new comments!